# Fix and move woo commerce category description below products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Move woocommerce category description below products

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
function custom_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) :
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
    endif;
}
```

I'm using this code right now for **product category descriptions** to show the description to the bottom of the page and the products show first. It's working but when I move to the next page of the same category, the description area disappears, I want to fix  the product category descriptions section for all product, and product category pages.

https://ethanza.com/product-category/sports-wear/nfl-uniform/

If you go to this link you can see the problem that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your hook as below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_archive_description', 20);
function custom_archive_description() {
    if (is_product_category()) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. It's adding descriptions before and after products, duplicating the description on the same page.

Comment: Edit it so that it will be fit to yours

Answer (score 0):

`add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
    function custom_archive_description(){
        if( is_product_category() ) :
            remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
        endif;
    }`

Can you try this code?

Comment: Not Working. It's making the description area to default area, which means it product category description shows before the products.

I want the same description section for all category pages, even when I navigate through the 2nd, and 3rd, page of the same category.

Comment: Hello.

add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 20);
function custom_archive_description() {
    if (is_product_category()) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5);
    }
}

Could you try this code structure?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Not working for me. When I tried your code, It adds the description twice on both the top and the bottom of the products.